# How to get foreign key object of a queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have three models Project, Member, User

```
class Project
    members = ManyToManyField(User, through="Member")

class User
    #...user model...

class Member
    project = ForeignKey(Project)
    user = ForeignKey(User)
    isAdmin = BooleanField(default=False)
```

If I wanted to get all the user objects of a project (p), I could do p.members.  But how can I easily get all the admins(user objects) of a project?

```
Member.filter(project=p, isAdmin=True) # this gets all the admin member objects
# how to convert this to user objects?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
User.objects.filter(member__isAdmin=True, member__project=p)
```

Django docs - [Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Comment: Please correct it to also filter by project p and then I'll check your answer. thx.